# Execute telnet command for Port check by SSH to remote hosts and get the output to a file

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a text file like below with `host`, `site` and `port` to telnet

```
      Hostname                site                  port
appwlsqa02.comp.xxx.com fgh-fst13-scan.comp.xxx.com 1521
appwlsqa03.comp.xxx.com fgh-fst23-scan.comp.xxx.com 1521
cappwlsqa01.comp.xxx.com fgh-fst13-scan.comp.xxx.com 1521
```

My goal is to ssh each `hostname` and execute telnet command

for example for the  first row in the file

```
ssh appwlsqa02.comp.xxx.com
```

then,

```
telnet fgh-fst13-scan.comp.xxx.com  1521
```

I have tried below:

```
while read HOST site port ; do ssh $HOST "echo exit | telnet $site $port " < /dev/null; done < text.txt`
```

I have to read `hostnames` as one variable `$HOST` and host to check as `$site` and port as`$port`

**Update:**

Here is the script i have developed based on sugegstions:

```
# /bin/bash
while read HOST site port ; 
do
echo $HOST $site $port  
ssh -n $HOST "telnet $site $port | grep "Connected" " >> t.txt &
PID=$!
sleep 2 
kill "$PID"

if [ -s t.txt ]
then
echo from $HOST to  $site $port is open >> succ.txt
else
echo from $HOST to  $site $port is closed >> fail.txt
fi
rm t.txt
done < text.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to use telnet, you need to run something like expect. Telnet grabs the terminal io. Expect replaces the terminal with a pseudo terminal and allows you to script the input and output.

Comment: I have some how managed to get the success scenerios but the fail cases the script is hunging up

Comment: Ok. Here is what you need to do.

Comment: Start the process off to the background. Then In the next statement get the background process Id into a variable. I think that it is in $!. Then start another process in the background that sleeps some amount of time and kills the first process id. You should put the 2 statements in parenthesis and background them both (sleep 15; kill $firstpid) &.  Then get that process id and wait on them both.  Wait $firstpid $secondpid.   The wait will return when either is dead. Then clean up the second process if it is still alive.

Comment: Thankyou Mike..It helped..Problem Solved :)